# property x does not exist on type '(props?: any) => ClassNameMap<"x">'

Tags: reactjs, makestyles

I have to create the styles based on a param, for that i have done as below.

```
 const useStyles = (isLayoutReadOnly = false) =>
  makeStyles((theme: Theme) => {
    return {
      x: {
        margin: theme.spacing(0, 0, 1, 0),
          marginLeft: !isLayoutReadOnly ? '-20px' : undefined 
        }
      }
    };
  });
```

And i am trying to use it this way,

```
 const { x } = useStyles(isLayoutReadOnly);
```

Which throws me the error

> property x does
> not exist on type '(props?: any) => ClassNameMap<"x">'

How should i fix this issue? I have tried setting the custom return types and also `ReturnType<typeof makeStyles>`, how ever, it is unable to detect.

Comment: What does your `makeStyles` function look like?

Comment: That is from materialUI 
/**
 * `makeStyles` where the passed `styles` do not depend on props
 */
`export default function makeStyles<Theme = DefaultTheme, ClassKey extends string = string>(
  style: Styles<Theme, {}, ClassKey>,
  options?: Omit<WithStylesOptions<Theme>, 'withTheme'>
): (props?: any) => ClassNameMap<ClassKey>;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are setting `useStyles` to **a function** that calls `makeStyles`:

```
const useStyles = (isLayoutReadOnly = false) => makeStyles()...
```

The example in the [docs](https://mui.com/system/styles/api/#makestyles-styles-options-hook) shows `useStyles` being *set to `makeStyles` directly* rather than to a function:

```
const useStyles = makeStyles((theme: Theme) =>
  createStyles({
    root: {
      backgroundColor: theme.palette.red,
    },
  }),
);
```

You can achieve the same pattern with your code by using an  [Immediately Invoked Function Expression](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/IIFE). By **wrapping your function in `(() => {})` parenthesis and then adding `()` parenthesis at the end**, you can call your function immediately to make sure `useStyles` gets the return value of your `(isLayoutReadOnly) => ...` function. Here's how that would look:

```
  const useStyles = ((isLayoutReadOnly = false) =>
  makeStyles((theme) => {
    return {
      x: {
        margin: theme.spacing(0, 0, 1, 0),
          marginLeft: !isLayoutReadOnly ? '-20px' : undefined 
        }
      }
  }))(isLayoutReadOnly);
```

The other option is to adjust how you are calling `useStyles`. You can add an additional set of parenthesis to your call to `useStyles` to **call the function that is returned** to get the expected behavior:

```
  const  {x}  = useStyles(isLayoutReadOnly)();
```

Comment: This answer helped me. The approach one is not working because, the function executed result is kept in `useStyles` and hence, further calls doesnt call the function with param to get the actual result. Second approach works, but it should be `const  {x}  = useStyles(isLayoutReadOnly)()`

Comment: Could you please edit the answer accordingly and i will accept it as answer.

Comment: Sure, just updated it. Does that look right?